# Seo friendly url - Unable to find a way to get the htaccess to rewrite the urls

Tags: .htaccess

Currently, my site has this url format:

https://example.com/blog/news.php?read=article-title-here

I would like to change this url to:
https://example.com/news/article-title-here

Any idea how to do this please? I tried this method but see no changes in the browser bar(even after emptying the cache):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^read=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^news/?$ %1.php? [R=301,L]
```

Also, where should the htaccess file be written?
in https://example.com/
or
https://example.com/blog/

Thank you in advance!

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in your `https://example.com/.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+blog/news\.php\?read=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^news/(.+?)/?$ blog/news.php?read=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are so good! One thing I have noticed is that I had to add these rules in both the public_html/ and public_html/blog folders, did I do this right? I tried to remove it from either folders and got 404 errors.

Comment: Quick question for you, let's say i wish to rewrite more urls, how can I add the new rules please as when I try to add more rules of the same, it still try to use the first rule for the rewrite, thank you.

Comment: Thank you ! No, normally you should only put it at the root. Unless I have not exactly understood where the destination file is located. If you place your new rules each time in separate folders (which is very good), you can place them after these, or in the .htaccess of the directory concerned.